# ECS Service "Steady" State Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I've been using the `aws ecs wait services-stable` command after deploying a new version of my ECS task definition to identify once the ECS cluster has started a task and it has reached the `RUNNING` state, which seems to be the definition for "stable".

I'm now looking for a way to keep querying the service to see once it registers the target with the target group and the health checks pass which normally is indicated by an event showing up on the ECS events log with the word "steady".

So far the only option I believe I got is to constantly query via `aws ecs describe-services` for the last event for that service and lookup the string `steady` in it.

Is anyone aware of a better way to do this in a script perhaps timing out after a certain number of seconds?

Comment: I don't think there is such command built-in with aws cli. However, if your `desired number` is more than 1, `aws ecs wait services-stable` will give you the same result.